# Flutter Screens hierarchy

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my Application i have 3 stateless screens, Screen "A", Screen "B", Screen "C".

in my material app i used Screen "A" as home.

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
              bodyColor: LightColors.kDarkBlue,
              displayColor: LightColors.kDarkBlue,
              fontFamily: 'Poppins'
            ),
      ),
      home: ScreenA(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ),
```

inside Screen "A" i am navigating to screen "B" and from screen "B" i am navigating to Screen "C".

**Inside Screen "A"**

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => ScreenB(),
  ),
);
```

**Inside Screen "B"**

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => ScreenC(),
  ),
);
```

But when i inspector the flutter layout i got like this.

**Actual**

ScreenA

- ScreenB
- ScreenC

**Excepted**

ScreenA

- ScreenB

  - ScreenC

I'm new to flutter. could anyone help me to explain or achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Your actual expectation and expected expectations is the same. `ScreenA - ScreenB - ScreenC`. Is that a typo ?

Comment: @T.TSage hi. yes it was a typo issue. edited

Comment: What do you need to do with that hierarchy?

Comment: @iKeepChangingName hi, what i wanted is that then i can inject provider for particular pages. assume if one of my provider is only needed inside screen B and screen C. so if i injected that provider in screen B i can obtain it in screen C since it is child screen of screen B. other wise i have to inject all providers in main app since i have all screens "B,C" and (new screens*) under screen A

Answer (score 0):

you could try a different approach to this. Maybe using named routes instead. 
You can do each screen as independent and then use the route to navigate through them.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes

in this way you can inject what you want in each separate page.

To do this you have to define the routes when creating your app:

```
MaterialApp(
 // Start the app with the "/" named route. In this case, the app starts
 // on the FirstScreen widget.
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
 // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
       '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
 // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
       '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
     },
    );
```

Then just call each route using the Navigator.pushNamed() method. For example if you do that inside a button.

```
//Within the `FirstScreen` widget
    onPressed: () {
//Navigate to the second screen using a named route.
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
     }
```